# How to remove the text from output of a ConvertTo-HTML -property command in powershell?

Tags: html, powershell, tags, ps

So, this is my query which I am running to fetch logs from a particular location:

```
$_serverlist = @(Get-Content "C:\Users\A1509886-a\Desktop\Test.txt" )
ForEach ($_server in $_serverlist)
{gci -Path "\\$_server\d$\Daksh\Logs\Secure3DS" | sort DateModified | select -Last 1 |  ConvertTo-Html -Property LastWriteTime,Directory,FullName | Out-File  "D:\Daksh\Logs\abc.html"}
```

for the same, I am getting output as three columned lists (as the property is mentioned:

```
Directory:\\\\$_server\d$\Daksh\Logs\abcd
LastWriteTime: time that it was last modified
FullName: \\$_server\d$\Daksh\Logs\abcd\ab.logs
```

So, is there a way that we can trim the Output result i.e., the text in the directory and full name? so to make them the **only name** instead of the whole path of Log file in Full Name and **only the name of the server** in Directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manipulate a read-only value your better off just creating a custom object and working from there...

```
$_serverlist = @(Get-Content "C:\Users\A1509886-a\Desktop\Test.txt")
ForEach ($_server in $_serverlist) {
    $gci = gci -Path "\\$_server\d$\Daksh\Logs\Secure3DS" | sort DateModified | select -Last 1 

    [pscustomobject]$ho = @{
        Directory = $_server
        LastWriteTime = $gci.LastWriteTime
        FullName = $gci.Name
    
    }
    $o = New-Object psobject -Property $ho
    $o |  ConvertTo-Html -Property LastWriteTime,Directory,FullName | Out-File  "D:\Daksh\Logs\abc.html"
}
```